# Use async calls in a blocking webRequest handler in chrome

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension that reads a database (firebase for now) info before redirecting the user to another page.

Right now I have successfully implemented the logic of static redirect by simply doing:

```
function examineUrl(details) {
  return {redirectUrl: 'https://www.example.com/'};
}
```

Then I would love to implement the async logic of reading from database. I read in [Use asynchronous calls in a blocking webRequest handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588679/use-asynchronous-calls-in-a-blocking-webrequest-handler) (It is a similar question but for firefox) that I can return a Promise, so I try that:

```
function examineUrl(details) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return resolve( {redirectUrl: 'https://www.example.com/'})
    });
}
```

But there is no redirect action happening in chrome. The documentation for chrome did not mention it https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest, either. So I wonder if there exists a workaround for this in chrome?

Comment: 1) **Chrome** extensions API doesn't support Promises, 2) **Chrome's** webRequest API doesn't wait for asynchronous response inside listeners with the only exception of onAuthRequired as noted in the documentation. In other words you can't use an asynchronously calculated result inside a webRequest listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for letting me know. I wish they could clarify what they don't do in the doc as well.

Comment: could you perhaps make a synchronous http request to the database server?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment goes, there is no such support in chrome.

My workaround is to embrace the asynchronous pattern by reading data in a different asynchronous block instead of inside the webRequest handler -- kudos for code restructure for a better implementation!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pull off a little fudge for this with a combination of the webRequest and tabs api, like so:

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((details) => {
    (async () => {
        const {tabId} = details;
        const response = await doMyAsynchronousThing();
        if (response.shouldRedirect) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: `<redirect_url>`});
        }
    })();
    return {}
}, {
    urls: ["*://*/*"],
    types: ["main_frame"]
}, []);
```

This won't actually stop the original request, so is of no use if you want to avoid hitting the original url completely. But, if your only goal is to redirect the user, this seems to work.

I have the following permissions set:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "*://*/*",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
  ]
```