# firefox extension browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest not redirecting after getting asynchronous response

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

here is my code that call a function to redirect the page using browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
redirect,
{
  urls: ["<all_urls>"],
  types: ["main_frame"],
},
["blocking"]
);
```

and redirect function:

```
function redirect(requestDetails){
 let redirection_url = "https://google.com/";
 let type = requestDetails.type;
 let url = requestDetails.url;
 var checkurl = ""
 var final_url = '';

if(url.includes("http://")){
   checkurl = url.split('http://')[1]
   final_url = 'https://'+checkurl;
}else if(url.includes("https://")){
  final_url = url;
}else{
  final_url = 'https://'+url;
}

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", final_url, true);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       return {
                cancel:true,
              };
    }else if(this.status == 0 && this.readyState == 4){
      return {
              redirectUrl: redirection_url,
            };
    }
};
}
```

I am returning redirectUrl or cancel on the basis of the url is working on https or not. If there is no https on the website then I want to redirect to google.com, the response is fine and code is fine but there is some delay in response so the listener is not redirecting after getting a response.

the listener is in blocking state but still not working, i found this answer on

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588679/use-asynchronous-calls-in-a-blocking-webrequest-handler)

and i am return the readystatechange but still it is not working, really appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: obviously i am talking about firefox, why you think that i asked this for chrome, where i have written that i want it in chrome, i asked only about firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple that we have to return a promise so we have a blocking behaviour untill we get a value from promise.

```
function redirect(requestDetails){

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let redirection_url = "https://google.com/";
let type = requestDetails.type;
let url = requestDetails.url;
var checkurl = ""
var final_url = '';

if(url.includes("http://")){
   checkurl = url.split('http://')[1]
   final_url = 'https://'+checkurl;
}else if(url.includes("https://")){
  final_url = url;
}else{
  final_url = 'https://'+url;
}

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", final_url, true);
xhttp.send();

var abc = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(xhttp, xhttp.status)
  if(xhttp.readyState == 4){

    if (xhttp.status == 200) {
      reject({  cancel: true });
    } else if(xhttp.status == 0 && xhttp.readyState == 4) {
      resolve({
        redirectUrl: redirection_url,
      });
    }
    clearInterval(abc)
  }
    
  
}, 1000);
});
}
```

Comment: Why it is not working in Manifest v3. No matter what listener is not blocking anything